# Looking for scifi novel published around mid-80s about a scientist who gets telepathic abilities from a drug he creates?

Tags: story-identification, books, telepathy

The story is about a scientist who makes a drug that gives him incredible telepathic abilities which he uses to help others. He later gives the drug to his girl friend so she can help him in his adventures.

Comment: Reminds me a little of Lucius Shepard's [*Life During Wartime.*](http://www.amazon.com/Life-During-Wartime-Lucius-Shepard/dp/0553290665/ref=tmm_mmp_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&sr=&qid=)

Answer (score 3):

A book that sounds similar is *[The Invisibles](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000H7WGZ8)* by Bernhardt J Hurwood, published in the  70's. The protagonist gets telepathic powers from an overdose of an experimental hallucinogen. He meets a women with telepathic powers and they go against evil doers